Is it possible to provide gtest type parameterized test macro a type list?
I find gtest type parameterized test very efficient in building unit tests. However, I wonder is it possible to avoid hard coded the types in ::testing::Types<>?
Here is example from gtest website:
using MyTypes = ::testing::Types<char, int, unsigned int>;
INSTANTIATE_TYPED_TEST_SUITE_P(My, FooTest, MyTypes);

I have been using boost mp11 for template meta programming (TMP). Using mp11, I can easily construct a list containing different types. Therefore, instead of hard coded char, int, unsigned int inside the ::testing::Types<>, I hope I can do something as following:
using L1 = mp_list_c<char, int, uint32_t>;
using MyTypes = ::testing::Types<L1>;
INSTANTIATE_TYPED_TEST_SUITE_P(My, FooTest, MyTypes);

The sample I present here seems not gain much since L1 is hard coded as well. However, if the ::testing::Types<> could accept a type list of some kind, I cold use TMP tricks to "dynamically" construct the type list. Is there a way to achieve what I want?

You can write a utility which will perform conversion:
template<typename T>
struct ToTestTypes;

template<template<typename ...> typename U, typename...Ts>
struct ToTestTypes<U<Ts...>>
{
    using type = ::testing::Types<Ts...>;
};

template<typename T>
using ToTestTypes_t = typename ToTestTypes<T>::type;

This converts instance of any type parametrized type template into respective gtest type: ::testing::Types< ... >, so it will work with mp_list_c.
I was unable to find gtest equivalent of this (maybe there is one).
Demo
